# Getting a parsing error when parsing with commas

Tags: php, arrays, file-io

I'm getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$array_of_lines' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\wamp\www\site6\book-utilities.inc.php on line 7.

I'm trying to use two classes to read in my separate files, the customer file should be read and each line be read into a new instance of an array. The orders file should be read into an array of order objects.

Here is what I have right now, am I doing this the wrong way?

```
<?php



class readOrders{

$array_of_lines = fopen("orders.txt", 'r') or die("Failed to create file");
  foreach($array_of_lines as $line) {
 $pieces_of_line = explode(',', $line); 

}

class readCustomers{
$array_of_more_lines = fopen("customers.txt", 'r') or die("Failed to create file");
  foreach($array_of_more_lines as $line) {
 $pieces_of_line = explode(',', $line);

}


?>
```

Here are my text files

Orders.txt

```
1,4,0133360903,Building Java Programs,Computer Science
2,6,0321836995,Mathematics All Around,Mathematics
3,24,0321825721,Mathematics for Elementary Teachers with Activity Manual,Mathematics
4,10,0133011208,Business Math,Business
5,10,0321836960,Elementary Statistics,Statistics
6,15,0321838696,Business Statistics: A First Course,Statistics
7,19,0133485102,Managing Engineering and Technology,Engineering
8,2,0133128911,Basics of Web Design: HTML5 & CSS3,Computer Science
9,2,0133068307,Introduction to JavaScript Programming with XML and PHP,Computer Science
10,3,0133251241,Horngren's Financial & Managerial Accounting,Business
11,18,0132948850,Survey of Economics,Economics
12,18,0132948869,Microeconomics,Economics
13,18,0132991330,Macroeconomics,Economics
14,18,0132992795,Macroeconomics, 2/e,Economics
15,16,0132730359,E-Commerce 2013,Business
16,29,0132993341,Fundamentals of Futures and Options Markets,Business
17,21,0132991306,Modern Systems Analysis and Design,Business
18,25,0321836960,Elementary Statistics,Statistics
19,25,0321838696,Business Statistics: A First Course,Statistics
20,5,0133255433,Horngren's Financial & Managerial Accounting, The Managerial Chapters,Business
21,5,0133255573,Horngren's Financial & Managerial Accounting. The Financial Chapters,Business
22,11,0205890962,Mosaics: Reading and Writing Essays 6e,Student Success
23,30,013335671X,Machine Design,Engineering
24,23,0136015727,Reliability Engineering,Engineering
25,23,0132832887,Aerodynamics for Engineers,Engineering
26,23,0321899970,Technical Communication,English
```

customers.txt

```
2,Leonie,Köhler,leonekohler@surfeu.de,University of Stuttgart,Theodor-Heuss-Straße 34,Stuttgart,,Germany,70174,+49 0711 2842222
3,Bjørn,Hansen,bjorn.hansen@yahoo.no,University of Oslo,Ullevålsveien 14,Oslo,,Norway,0171,+47 22 44 22 22
4,François,Tremblay,ftremblay@gmail.com,McGill University,1498 rue Bélanger,Montréal,QC,Canada,H2G 1A7,+1 (514) 721-4711
5,František,Wichterlová,frantisekw@jetbrains.com,Charles University,Klanova 9/506,Prague,,Czech Republic,14700,+420 2 4172 5555
6,Astrid,Gruber,astrid.gruber@apple.at,Vienna University of Technology,Rotenturmstraße 4, Vienna,,Austria,1010,+43 01 5134505
7,Helena,Holý,hholy@gmail.com,Charles University,Rilská 3174/6,Prague,,Czech Republic,14300,+420 2 4177 0449
16,Aaron,Mitchell,aaronmitchell@yahoo.ca,University of Manitoba,696 Osborne Street,Winnipeg,MB,Canada,R3L 2B9,+1 (204) 452-6452
17,Ellie,Sullivan,ellie.sullivan@shaw.ca,Aurora College,5112 48 Street,Yellowknife,NT,Canada,X1A 1N6,+1 (867) 920-2233
18,João,Fernandes,jfernandes@yahoo.pt,University of Lisbon,Rua da Assunção 53,Lisbon,,Portugal,,+351 (213) 466-111
19,Madalena,Sampaio,masampaio@sapo.pt,University of Porto,4350 Rua dos Campeões Europeus de Viena, Porto,,Portugal,,+351 (225) 022-448
22,Isabelle,Mercier,isabelle_mercier@apple.fr,University of Burgundy,68 Rue Jouvence,Dijon,,France,21000,+33 03 80 73 66 99
23,Emma,Jones,emma_jones@hotmail.com,King's College,202 Hoxton Street,London,,United Kingdom,N1 5LH,+44 020 7707 0707
```

Comment: You should read up on classes and objects in php: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class can only have methods and property definitions directly between the braces `{ }`. Also, you didn't close your foreach loops.

It appears you want to run your code in the constructor:

```
class readOrders{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $array_of_lines = fopen("orders.txt", 'r') or die("Failed to create file");
        foreach($array_of_lines as $line) {
            $pieces_of_line = explode(',', $line);
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Would a return or set an internal variable be best for the constructor here? Currently it's modifying values but then having no use

Comment: @MattTingle can you elaborate on how you want to interact with the two classes and the desired data structures for both? Have you got an Order class or do you want to use stdClass?

Comment: Well, I'm going to be displaying the customer data into a table.

Comment: By the way, this did work, no errors, and my die message is not showing.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally bad practice to have more than one class per file. The issue is likely generated from the missing a closing curly bracket on your foreach loop on both classes:

```
class readOrders{
   public function __construct(){
       $array_of_lines = fopen("orders.txt", 'r') or die("Failed to create file");
       foreach($array_of_lines as $line) {
           pieces_of_line = explode(',', $line); 
       }    
   }
}

class readCustomers{
    public function __construct(){
       $array_of_more_lines = fopen("customers.txt", 'r') or die("Failed to create file");
       foreach($array_of_more_lines as $line) {
          $pieces_of_line = explode(',', $line);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this even valid syntax for classes? Shouldn't this be wrapped in a public function with a return?

Comment: You're 100% right, the whole structure is invalid in the posted code. I assumed he didn't post all his code / left out the obvious.

Comment: The error message points out the flaw aha, update your answer accordingly for a +1 from me